# dynamic VectorDrawable animation in Java instead of animated vector drawable

Tags: java, android, android-vectordrawable, animatedvectordrawable

I have been using the `animated-vector` in xml to animate some of my vectors by using `trimPathEnd` etc  with something like this for example :

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:drawable="@drawable/vectordrawable" >
  <target android:name="main_path">
<aapt:attr name="android:animation">
  <objectAnimator
    android:duration="1000"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_linear_in"
    android:propertyName="trimPathEnd"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="1"/>
</aapt:attr>
</target>
</animated-vector>
```

However I would like to know if it is possible to trimPathEnd or trimPathStart without having to use an animation, this is because I would like to achieve a layout where the vector gets drawn based on a screen touch offset, so I guess something like `vector.setTrimPathEnd(0.2f);` is what I would need to dynamically change the path end in Java based on a specific offset. All the info I could find was to get this done via an `animated-vector` which is not the behavior I need here.

Comment: Downvotes are welcome to add a comment maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what [Lottie](http://airbnb.io/lottie/android/avd.html) document says:

> **Pros of Lottie vs AnimatedVectorDrawable**
>
> - Supports a much larger set of After Effects features.
> - Manually set progress to hook up an animation to a gesture, event, etc. > - Download animations from the network.
> - Dynamic playback speed.
> - Masks are anti-aliased.
> - Dynamically change the color of a specific part of an animations

What it mentions is `Lottie` can `Manually set progress` and AVD cannot. I can't find any Android official document for this but I believe it's true because if you look at the `AnimatedVectorDrawable` code, no method allows you to get or set the animation progress.

So consider using `Lottie` instead, many cool features and a whole bunch of [community resources](http://lottiefiles.com/)